Range of $\frac{2x}{2-x^2}$ for $x \in [-1,1[$
Range of $\dfrac{2x}{2-x^2}$ for $x \in [-1,1[$I know how to find the range of this function if it is defined over $\Bbb R$, that it set it equal to $y$, make cases for value of $y$, solve both the linear case and the quadratic one for real values of $x$ in terms of $y$.
But I don't know how to start if the function is defined on a subset of $\Bbb R$ as it is now....
Just a simple hint would work

Range of a continuous function is an interval.

And then? Like how to simplify it a bit so that I could do the rest by myself

You asked for a  simple hint and I gave one. Do you see any connection of the end points of the interval with max and min of the function?

Thank you sir. All clear now. I was worries about those asymptotes and all in the graph.

You are right to worry about them, but you'll notice that the asymptotes $x = \pm \sqrt 2 \approx \pm 1,41$ are both outside the range we're interested, hence your graph is connected, hence the method in @ABlack's answer works.

You can use the method you described. Just see when $2x = y(2-x^2)$ has solutions for x in [-1, ). Simly check if the determinant is greater than 0 and see which solutions you get.

@ABlack I liked your solution sir. But I'm not sure about how can I use my method for limited values of x. We use D>0 so that we get x in R but I'm not sure how to use it in this question.

@ABlack I am done with the question but I would like to know how can I solve by putting it equal to y and then that discriminant stuff? Let me try once

Your function is continuous on $(-1, 1)$; let's look at its derivative:
$$f'(x) = \frac{2(2 - x^2) + 2x \cdot 2x}{(2 - x^2)^2} = \frac{2(x^2 + 2)}{(2 - x^2)^2}$$
Since the derivative is positive on $(-1, 1)$, the function is increasing (it's monotone). Hence its range is an interval $[f(-1), f(1)) = [-2, 2)$

Nice. As an alternative way to see its increasing, we can see that the numerator and denominator are both continuous, the numerator is increasing, the denominator is decreasing, and the denominator never crosses zero (since that only happens when $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$.

This is not an algebra-precalculus solution though...

@Sil the author didn’t mention that the solution should use (or don’t use) methods from pre calculus

They did through tag. But who knows, maybe they will accept calculus solution. Actually it seems OP used both calculus and precalculus tags to make things even more confusing

@Sil Actually I wanted to see more variations in solutions. :)

$y:= \dfrac{2x}{2-x^2}:$
Note that the function is odd.
Let $0\le x \le 1:$ Then $y \ge 0$
$y(0)=0;$ $y(1)=2;$
The function $2x$, numerator, is increasing.
The function $2-x^2$, denominator, is decreasing.
Hence $y=f(x)$ is increasing in $[0,1].$
Maximum at $x=1:$ $y=2.$
We have:
$y_{range} =[0,2]$ for $x \in [0,1],$
$y=f(x)$ is odd, can you finish?

Oh yes sir... We can reflect y = f(x) in origin... And that thing would also be increasing so the minima at x = -1 which is -2 so the overall range is [-2,2]. Thanks sir. Nice :)

Darshit. Yes, exactly.  Thanks, Peter
